# When I select and attempt to move every other face in a row, all faces are moved instead

Tags: selection-tools, faces

[image][image]This is very odd, as I was able to do what I am attempting to do on the opposite side of the indentation as shown in the screen captures, though when I first attempted it on that side, it was doing what it's doing now, moving the entire row of faces as opposed to the ones that are selected exclusively. a

Comment: is proportional editing on? (look in the 3D view header.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've never used proportional editing.

Comment: How do you expect to move those faces without moving the adjacent ones without detaching them, if they are contiguous? Only if you created new faces, or somehow extruded them. Only way you could have successfully moved the ones on the opposite side was if you had previously extruded them by accident and left them in place overlapping. Anyway, what you want is to **extrude** not move them. Press the `E` key

Comment: Apparently that had something to do with it, but extruding them wasn't working before either, because it was leaving the face on the top in place while sinking the vertical face into it. like a four-sided hollow box.

Comment: Nevermind. I am just pushing the row back and then extruding outward instead.